# How do I ensure that certain model instances are always present in django database?

Tags: python, django, django-models

My django-application requires a few model instances to always be present in the database to function properly.

I currently create the model instances that I require in the `Appconfig.ready(self)` method for the corresponding app. This way the instances are always present on boot of the django-application. This works but not as well as I'd like, I have to be careful when deleting objects so that I do not delete the required objects.

I would like the required model instances to be undeletable or preferably, be created whenever they are not present in the database.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your solution about protecting certain objects from deletion in you problem. To do this there are two ways I can think of:

- When deletion is happening check to see if object is protected or not
- Tweak admin permissions and do not let anyone delete the object from admin panel

The main difference is in first way your only way to delete protected objects is from your database command line interface, However in second way the model can be deleted in code.

For the first way you need to override [delete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.delete) method of the model and check something like this

```py
assert pk != self.protected_objects
```

Where protected objects list is a property of your model class.

For second way you would do

```py
class YourModel(admin.ModelAdmin):
    protected_objects = [1,2,...]
    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return obj.pk not in self.protected_objects
```